# Problem passing and returning a view android

Tags: android, android-studio

I pass a BlurView (added from the library) to this class and then get it in MainActivity (using getBlurView) the BlurView is passed correctly but the problem is mBlurView returns null!
Can anyone please help me with it?

Thank you so much ...

```
public class Blur {

private BlurView mBlurView;

public Blur(BlurView blurView)
{
    mBlurView = blurView;
}

public BlurView getBlurView()
{
    return mBlurView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening because there is no class constructor.

```
public class Blur {

    private BlurView mBlurView;
    
    // Add this constructor to the class
    public Blur(BlurView blurView) {
        this.mBlurView = blurView;
    }

    public void setBlurView(BlurView blurView) {
        mBlurView = blurView;
    }

    public BlurView getBlurView() {
        return mBlurView;
    }
}
```